# allow user to download dynamic csv file asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to allow my user to click on a button that says "download" and then will build a dynamic csv file on the fly and will prompt the user to download.   I know how to build the file using a HTTPHandler, but not quite sure the mechanism for delivering the content via download.

Answer (score 11):

I usually create a Generic Handler (.ashx) and do something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   StringBuilder myCsv = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(myRow r in myRows) {
     myCsv.AppendFormat("\"{0}\",{1}", r.MyCol1, r.MyCol2);
   }

   context.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
   context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.csv");
   context.Response.Write(myCsv.ToString());
}
```

Now if the CSV you're building is REALLY big, you might want to write out each row as you create it, rather than stuffing it into a StringBuilder.

Comment: Just a small addition to the above code: I found I needed to add 
context.Response.Flush();

context.Response.End();

to my code when I implemented something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just emit a `Content-Disposition` HTTP header in your HTTP Handler code. Most browsers will interpret that as a download request. Replace `yourfile.csv` by the filename you want the user to see.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourfile.csv");
```